# Using VB as automation, I want to tick the PowerPoint option box "Do not compress images in file"

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint

I'm adding a feature to a program that copies a file from Surfer and pastes it to a PowerPoint slide.  The Surfer image is large, and I need to only have a small portion of the Surfer file visible in the framing of the PowerPoint slide.

The problem I'm having is that when I open powerpoint, the default is to have any copied and pasted images compressed.  Whatever is showing in the PowerPoint slide is blurry because of the compression.  When I do it without automation and turn off image compression, it looks perfect.

Please note that this program is not just for me, it's to be distributed to others within the company, so I can't expect other people who want to use this program to change their default settings.  I just want to figure out how to turn off compression.

Here's what I have so far:

```
        'Opens Surfer
        objSurferApp = CreateObject("Surfer.Application")
        'Open Powerpoint
        objPPTAPP = CreateObject("powerpoint.application")
        objPPTMapSeries = objPPTAPP.presentations.add

        'copies image from Surfer
        objSurferMap.shapes.selectall()
        objSurferMap.selection.copy()

        slidecount = objPPTMapSeries.Slides.Count

        'Adds a new slide
        objPPTMapSeries.Slides.Add(slidecount + 1, PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutBlank)

        'pastes image to PowerPoint slide
        objPPTMapSeries.Slides(slidecount + 1).Shapes.Paste()
        objSurferMap.close()
```

I don't have any ideas except for bundling a template PPT with the program with the checkbox already ticked, but that doesn't seem too elegant of a solution.  Thanks for your consideration.  I'm relatively new to programming and very new to stackoverflow, so please let me know if there's anything obvious I should be seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the compression settings are not exposed via the object model.  You can turn compresson on/off via a reg setting though.  Here are the manual instrux.  And you really do need to do this when PPT isn't running, else it won't work.

Close Power Point

Open registry editor (Start /Run and type Regedit)

Go to  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\PowerPoint\Options].  Change that "12.0" to "14.0" for PowerPoint 2010 or "15.0" for PowerPoint 2013.

Create a new Dword value named AutomaticPictureCompressionDefault

Make sure that the value of the new Dword is 0

Close registry editor

Now, by default, PowerPoint does not compress pictures. If we want to enable compression, go back to the same registry key and change the value from 0 to 1.